# Django traverse through relations

Tags: python, django

I've got some models which relations like this:

```
class Conversion(models.Model):

    class Unit(models.IntegerChoices):
        g   = 10, 'gramy',
        ml  = 20, 'mililitry',
        qty = 30, 'sztuki'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    g = models.FloatField()
    ml = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    qty = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    default = models.IntegerField(choices=Unit.choices, default=Unit.g)

class Ingredient(models.Model):

    class Unit(models.IntegerChoices):
        g   = 10, 'gramy',
        dkg = 11, 'dekagramy',
        kg  = 12, 'kilogramy',
        ml  = 20, 'mililitry',
        l   = 21, 'litry',
        qty = 30, 'sztuki'

    Conversion = models.ForeignKey(Conversion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    unit = models.IntegerField(choices=Unit.choices, default=Unit.g)

class Step(models.Model):
    body = models.JSONField()
    Ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='steps')

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    teaser = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Steps = models.ManyToManyField(Step, blank=True, related_name='recipes')
```

Say there's a conversion for flour where 1ml == .53g, and the steps are separated because of how they are displayed so I thought it would be best to put it all into separate models.

Now if a user tells me he has some amount(Ingredients.amount) of ingredients(Conversion) I want to find all recipes that have equal or less of these.

for example user chooses 3 ingresients:
|conversion.pk|amount|
|-------------|------|
|1            |200   |
|2            |300   |
|3            |1000  |

If a recipe has steps.conv.pk 1 and 2 with right amount but doesn't have the 3rd one, I want to find it too.

Comment: I feel like this might be one of those times you might consider de-normalizing the Ingredient model and build out something like a set of fields to hold the calculated amounts. So if upon creation the thing takes 25 ml of something, you do the calculations to all other units then and store in the appropriate fields. This has the benefit of faster and easier searching/filtering later as you are not having to recalculate out everytime time it is needed. Think of it as a cached result if you don't like the term denormalize.

Comment: @AMG you do have a point here, it would be much easier to filter it but then I would not be able to populate conversions with all sorts of ingredients and user would have to manually type the name and configure the conversions for each ingredient in each step.

Comment: make that part automatic using the same conversion method you were going to do before on every search. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the workflow.

Comment: What I'm suggesting might be what Conversion already is?

Comment: A Conversion is a specific type of ingredient (didn't want to name it Type because of py built-ins). For example there can be a convertion with name Flour, g = .53 and ml = 1. All units should correspond to each other as equal. In thatg example 1 ml of flour = .53g. That means wou can look at a recipe someone made and if you need to you can convert the units of measurements. Ingredient is a wrapper that says: Type of ingredient + amount in default unit for the type + the way it should be displayed in the recipe. Eg. recipe needs 1000g of flour so just display it in kg.

Comment: This way there can be a database for predefined types of ingredients so when you make a recipe you just type the name, put amount and if you wish to you can change the displayed unit. For the search it will be similar. You have 3 fields, ingr. type, amount and dropdown of units by default set to the default type's unit. I made it this way so if you live in a different country or don't have a weight you can just conv it to ounces or say glasses and measure it approximately this way. Thank you for genuine interest. It's just a concept app I want to build around this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got this understood correctly, and I might not, I think you are adding ingredients to each step. The ingredients have a quantity and unit and a Conversion which stores the ingredient name with a base amount and unit. Where I'm getting a little off on the understanding is knowing the difference between Ingredient.amount, Conversion.qty. Is the Conversion.g and Conversion.ml the conversion factor from Conversion.default to that unit?

In any case, I think you want to move steps out of Recipe as a many to many field, and put a foreign key in Step to Recipe. From a stylistic recommendation, I'd also suggest naming all your fields with lowercase (so Step.Ingredients becomes Step.ingredients) as it will make life simpler later on always knowing if you are looking at the class or the property.

I'm also not convinced you want ingredients in Step as a many to many as your quantities are associated with Ingredients. This means if you have a recipe pointing to 1 cup of Flour, and you later have another recipe using that same record, but decide to change it to 3/4 cups of flour, your original recipe will pick up that change. I believe you want Ingredient to have a foreign key to step (but I didn't make that change below).

Here is what I'd suggest for a starting point (but think Ingredient should not be many-to-many of step).

```
from django.db import models


class Conversion(models.Model):
    class Unit(models.IntegerChoices):
        g = 10, 'gramy',
        ml = 20, 'mililitry',
        qty = 30, 'sztuki'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    g = models.FloatField()
    ml = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    qty = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    default = models.IntegerField(choices=Unit.choices, default=Unit.g)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    class Unit(models.IntegerChoices):
        g = 10, 'gramy',
        dkg = 11, 'dekagramy',
        kg = 12, 'kilogramy',
        ml = 20, 'mililitry',
        l = 21, 'litry',
        qty = 30, 'sztuki'

    conversion = models.ForeignKey(Conversion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    unit = models.IntegerField(choices=Unit.choices, default=Unit.g)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.amount} {self.conversion} [{self.Unit(self.unit).label}] ({self.unit})"


class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    teaser = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Step(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='steps')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[:50]
```

Some admin.py just for the fun of it.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from recipe_15285278.models import Recipe, Ingredient, Step, Conversion


@admin.register(Step)
class StepAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class StepInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Step


@admin.register(Recipe)
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    inlines = [StepInline, ]


@admin.register(Ingredient)
class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(Conversion)
class ConversionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I'm not convinced this is the right architecture for what you are trying to build but if it is, one can start here to build out the queries. I've changed the step to `TextField` as I'm using sqllite which doesn't support the `JSONField`.

[image]

Comment: The Conversion object stores name and default unit of measurement for each type on ingredient. for example Flour, default in grams or water, default in milliliters. All the other fields are corresponding to each other as the same amount of ingredient but in different unit. For water you would put 1g = 1ml or 10g = 10ml. For flour you can say that 53g = 100ml. I really like your edits and you're right about M2M not being the best options for ingredients. Also, conversion.qty is reserved for ingredients like cherry tomato (will require grams too so everything can be converted to weight)

Comment: The model you made is really good for what I need but how do I search for a recipe that the user will be able to make using given ingredients they have.
For example, how to find the recipe you made in the admin panel when I have enough of butter and bread but also I have, say, 100g of tomatoes?

Comment: Yes, I think Conversion needs a rename to Ingredient, steps should not hold ingredients (they should belong to the recipe not the steps), and there should be a through table for ingredients from recipe that holds the quantity for this recipe. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ingredients are divided into steps because of how the editor works and how it all will be displayed. User should be able to view each step separately. The editor will look a bit like this: konopka.me/editor (also this is how it will be displayed: https://konopka.me/inc/foodlog/Tort.svg ). I'm also thinking about post-processing each recipe on submit so it has it's own list of ingredients. That would probably be the best option as each step could have the same ingredient in some amount. Also the search would be much easier.

Comment: ah, I see, almost like sub recipes making up the full dish. I understand now - thank you. Those look good!